# How to get list of all files from a directory (including its sub-directories) whose file name contains a specific string

Tags: linux

I want to retrieve the list of files from  a directory & including its sub-directories too, Whose file name contains "**message-**" or "**secure**". I have tried with below commands , But they could not read files from its sub-directories.

```
find /u01 -maxdepth 1 -name "*message-*"

find . -name "*message-*"

find /u01 -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -20 | find  -maxdepth 1 -name "*message-*" -a -name "*secure*"
```

Can you please help on this...

Comment: Remove  -maxdepth 1   just use                     
 find /u01 -name "*message-*"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below commands worked for me.

```
find /u01 -type f \( -name "*message*" -o -name "*secure*" \)   -type f -printf '%s %p\n'
```

To get top 20 largest file whose name contains those both string.

```
find /u01 -type f \( -name "*message*" -o -name "*secure*" \)   -type f -printf '%s %p\n' | sort -nr | head -20
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use like below will work i think:

```
find . -type f -iname "*message-*" -o -iname "*secure*"
```